# AutoMapper DynamicMap object vs anonymous type

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, automapper

In following simple scenario why is it that the output of TestMethod1 is "test" and the output of TestMethod2 is null? Moreover if you change the order and run TestMethod2 first both methods will output null.

I just started to work with AutoMapper and I don't have a lot of experience and I really need to make this method (with object as parameter) to work. Can someone please explain to me why does it work like this and what I can do about it?

```
public partial class TestClass
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestMethod1();
        TestMethod2(new { Test = "test" });
    }

    public static void TestMethod1()
    {
        TestClass test = new TestClass();

        Mapper.DynamicMap(new { Test = "test" }, test);
        Console.Out.WriteLine(test.Test);
    }

    public static void TestMethod2(object obj)
    {
        TestClass test = new TestClass();

        Mapper.DynamicMap(obj, test);
        Console.Out.WriteLine(test.Test);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
TestClass test = new TestClass();

Mapper.DynamicMap(obj, test);
```

you can use

```
TestClass test = (TestClass)Mapper.DynamicMap(obj, obj.GetType(), typeof(TestClass));
```

Use this in both cases; i.e. don't create an instance of `TestClass` - instead let Automapper do that)

This isn't a direct answer (yet) but more of a workaround; am not sure why what I wrote works and what you wrote doesn't - am investigating further

Comment: Thanks, your workaround works! In my case I need to Map to existing object but it also works: Mapper.DynamicMap(obj, test, obj.GetType(), typeof(TestClass)). Thanks alot for your answer.